# Box: How to download a file to a specific folder?

Tags: box-api

I'm using java sdk provided by box and I saw in the documentation, how to download a file:

```
String fileID = "11111";
BoxFile file = new BoxFile(api, fileID);
BoxFile.Info info = file.getInfo();

FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(info.getName());
file.download(stream);
stream.close();
```

I'm able to download it, but it's putting everything inside my project structure and I want to give a specific path so I can get all my outputs there.

Comment: How to get the fileID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the BoxFile documentation does not provide an attribute for the file path, where to store the downloaded file.

But the API for the FileOutPutStream is providing a solution for this:

```
new FileOutputStream("this/path/to/my/file.txt");
```

You can find all possible values for the constructor of this class under https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/io/FileOutputStream.html

Comment: For Rafael Osipov: Here is a very good explanation of what the Boxfile.Info does: https://github.com/box/box-java-sdk/blob/master/doc/files.md

The getName() only gives back the name provided with the constructor of the BoxFile. The BoxFile itself in Java has no FilePath!